# Outlook window blocks access to Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I have Windows.Forms application from which i need to open Outlook and programmatically fill address and subject. After this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
oMailItem.To = sto;
oMailItem.Subject = sid;
oMailItem.Display(true);
```

Outlook blocks access to the Windows.Forms application. But I need to copy some data from Windows.Forms app manually to the email body. I can't find good solution. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your last line to:

```
oMailItem.Display(false);
```

The modal argument means that the form will be blocked by the mail window

Comment: Thank you very much! That was so simple. I've searched wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

need to use: `oMailItem.Display();`

> Display(Modal): True to make the window modal. The default value is False.

REF:[MailItem.Display Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861853.aspx)